# Delete extra slashes in Excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a very long spreadsheet with thousands of lines like this:

new-dept/Tax/Affiliate/logs/Final//////

Due to some Text to Columns, I ended up with multiple slashes at the end of every line, some have only 3, some as many as 7.

I cannot do a Find and Replace for "/////", as it returns nothing.  Any ideas on how to delete all the slashes at the end of each line?

Comment: It might be easier to find every instance of "//" and replace with "/" recursively..

Comment: Theres other wacky stuff going on here.  Example: If I try to just hit the backspace until all the "///////" are gone on one line, it actually ends up removing those slashes and part of the text of the next word, even though I did not backspace over that word...

Comment: Your data is messed up, that's why you can't find and replace as well as why the macro isn't working. You need to restructure the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are OK with a single / at the end or not.

I'm going to assume it is OK.

This is a hack this for a quick answer, simply do find and replace multiple times

So, find /////// (7 slashes) and replace with nothing. Do the whole document

Then, find ////// (6 slashs) and replace with nothing for the whole document.

Continue until you end with `new-dept/Tax/Affiliate/logs/Final/`

---

I don't know why your Excel can't search for `/`, so I've written a macro (more of a test to see if this works or not).

Please use this Macro. Within the ribbon, [in the developer bar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/show-the-developer-tab-or-run-in-developer-mode-HA010173052.aspx), click Visual Basic, then double click on ThisWorkbook and paste the following

```
Sub RemoveTrailingSlahes()

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

      If (cell.Value <> "") Then
      Dim content As String
      content = cell.Value

      Dim cellContentSplit() As String

      'split the string
      cellContentSplit = Split(content, "/")

      Dim result As String
      result = ""

      'now rebuild it
      For i = 0 To UBound(cellContentSplit)

      If cellContentSplit(i) <> "" Then

        If (result <> "") Then
        result = result & "/"
        End If

        result = result & cellContentSplit(i)

      End If

      Next i

      cell.Value = result

      End If

Next

End Sub
```

It will read every cell in use, and it will remove the / from the end of each cell.

Before running macro's, take a back up of the work first in case it doesn't do what you were hoping for.

To run the macro, click, the green play button.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I try, and get the error message "Microsoft Excel cannot find any date to replace.  Check if your search formatting and criteria are defined correctly..."  And I would like to have no slashes at the end.

Comment: Does it work for other search phrases? I mean, if you search for Tax does it find it?

Comment: Yes it does.  It finds words and even hyphen symbol and single slash

Comment: @James, I've updated my answer, with a macro to see if this helps

Comment: I get an error message:  "Compile error:  Invalid outside procedure" with "cell" highlighted in the first If statement.

Comment: Did you copy this into the `ThisWorkbook`? Make sure you copy the entire macro. How is the data populated @James?

Comment: Macro appears to be running.  Copy and pasted directly from here.  Nothing is happening.  Made sure I pasted in "ThisWorkbook" under the VBAProject filename.  Dont know why this wont work!

Comment: I think Raystafarian is right.  I need to start over with my data, but your macro looks like its gonna do the trick, so thank you very much!